# Eclipse not able to load Java ImageMagick library in Mac OS X 10.11.4

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, imagemagick, osx-elcapitan

I have added the location of `ImageMagick` binary in `.bash_profile` as shown below:-

```
export MAGICK_HOME="$HOME/software/ImageMagick-7.0.1"
launchctl setenv MAGICK_HOME $MAGICK_HOME
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"
launchctl setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

But when ever I am launching my java app on Eclipse I am getting the below error:-

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "identify": error=2, No such file or directory
```

But whenever I am executing `identify` from command line it is working:-

```
jabongs-MacBook-Pro-4:~ debraj$ identify
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/debraj/software/ImageMagick-7.0.1/bin/identify
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15206961/785523) answer and added `ProcessStarter.setGlobalSearchPath("/Users/debraj/software/ImageMagick-7.0.1/bin");`. But then it started giving error `dyld: Library not loaded: /ImageMagick-7.0.1/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.0.dylib`

Can some one let me know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with eclipse. ImageMagick was installed from MacOSX Binary release as mentioned [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php). This was creating issues.

After installing ImageMagick as below:-

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew install imagemagick
```

and then setting GlobalSearchPath in my Java app as shown below solved the issue:-

```
ProcessStarter.setGlobalSearchPath("/usr/local/bin/");
```